# How to customize sylius_taxon_image_widget without modifying the vendor?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I need change imagine_filter('sylius_small') to imagine_filter('sylius_admin_product_original')

file path =>
Sylius\vendor\sylius\sylius\src\Sylius\Bundle\UiBundle\Resources\views\Form\imagesTheme.html.twig

```
{% block sylius_taxon_image_widget %}
    {% apply spaceless %}
        {{ form_row(form.type) }}
        {% if form.vars.value.path|default(null) is null %}
            <label for="{{ form.file.vars.id }}" class="ui icon labeled button"><i class="cloud upload icon"></i> {{ 'sylius.ui.choose_file'|trans }}</label>
        {% else %}
            <img class="ui small bordered image" src="{{ form.vars.value.path|imagine_filter('sylius_small') }}" alt="{{ form.vars.value.type }}" />
            <label for="{{ form.file.vars.id }}" class="ui icon labeled button"><i class="cloud upload icon"></i> {{ 'sylius.ui.change_file'|trans }}</label>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="ui hidden element">
            {{ form_widget(form.file) }}
        </div>
        <div class="ui element">
            {{- form_errors(form.file) -}}
        </div>
    {% endapply %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Copy the file to `templates/bundles/SyliusUiBundle/Form/imagesTheme.html.twig`
https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/customization/template.html
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#templates